# How does vmem parameter impact a kdb-q service

Tags: memory-management, kdb, q-lang

Here is what I did:

1. Ran a q process with a limiting `vmem` argument
   (say in a 100GB system, running `vmem` of 50GB)
2. Logged a unix `top` command

After the entire process was completed, I was trying to analyse the memory usage. I saw that the process %age memory usage crossed 90% mark. I believed that vmem restricts the memory consumption. But it seems that my process used more than 90GB memory at times.

How can this be explained? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info maybe? What exactly were your cmd-line args when starting q? Were you monitoring the "VIRT" field of the top command?

Comment: i had passed -vmem x in the cmd-line arg for starting q process.
i am monitoring %MEM field of the TOP command

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a valid cmd line arg. You need to use "-w". For example:

"q -w 50000"

Starts a q process with a 50gb memory limit. See http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Cmdline

Comment: I see. I think I mixed concepts. I had earlier understood that -w limits the memory for execution of a query from external source. Arggh. This makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: if you can post this as an answer, i would like to mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As #terrylynch said, command line parameter "-w" is used to set memory cap in kdb/q process. I checked and found that "-vmem" is not a kdb command line parameter.

vmem, in this context, is used in unix to manage memory of processes.

Comment: Good! As for "limiting memory for execution of a query from an external source" - there is no in-built way to control this but generally you can use gateway processes to be a middle-man between the external source and the database (rdb or hdb). This way if an inefficient query hits the memory limit it will not bring down the rdb/hdb, it will only kill the gateway process.

Comment: thanks very much!!i was able to analyse my process and am working on making it more efficient